# onclick open window

Tags: plugins

I am using AS-PDF plugin in WordPress. In this plugin, For opening new window, I would like to add onclick events in it like that

```
function as_pdf_link( $strContent ){
global $wp_query;

$strHtml = '
                <div id="aspdf">
                    <a target="_new" href="' . get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-content/plugins/as-pdf/generate.php?post=' . $wp_query->post->ID .'"onclick="open(this.href, this.target, 'width=600, height=450, top=200, left=250'); return false;">
                                <span>' . stripslashes( get_option( 'as_pdf_linktext' ) ) . '</span>
                            </a>     
                        </div>
                    ';

return $strContent . $strHtml;
```

}

But It doesn't work. So, please guide me how to do. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier it was giving you error. Try this. I have fixed errors in PHP syntax.

```
function as_pdf_link( $strContent ){
    global $wp_query;

    $strHtml = '
                <div id="aspdf">
                    <a target="_new" href="' . get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-content/plugins/as-pdf/generate.php?post=' . $wp_query->post->ID . '" onclick="open(this.href, this.target, \'width=600, height=450, top=200, left=250\'); return false;">
                        <span>' . stripslashes( get_option( 'as_pdf_linktext' ) ) . '</span>
                    </a>     
                </div>
                ';

    return $strContent . $strHtml;
}
```

Comment: Sure no problem. :)